# GWT (2.4.0) + XSRF

Tags: gwt, asynchronous, rpc, csrf

I've been trying to get XSRF working on a webapp to no avail.
I am looking at a typical login implementation.

I am following [Google's code](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideSecurityRpcXsrf).
I changed my web.xml to include:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>xsrf</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.XsrfTokenServiceServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>xsrf</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/gwt/xsrf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>gwt.xsrf.session_cookie_name</param-name>
    <param-value>JSESSIONID</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and extended `XsrfProtectedServiceServlet` on the server Impl file of my login service. It is my understanding that no other change is needed on the server. Do I need to add anything else, such as a method that returns an `RpcToken` here (as well as in the interface I am implementing)?

On the client side, I use annotations.

```
@XsrfProtect
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("login")
public interface LoginService extends RemoteService {
    String check(String user, String pass) throws IllegalArgumentExceptionhere;
}
```

This is probably where I am missing something. Google says on the tip: `Tip: To specify which RpcToken implementation GWT should generate serializers for use @RpcTokenImplementation annotation.` Not sure what that means or if I need another method here to return an RpcToken.

My async interface is like this:

```
public interface LoginServiceAsync {
    //Returns the Session ID
    void check(String user, String pass, AsyncCallback<String> callback);
}
```

Then for my actual RPC call, I wrap my code around the xsrf token request. I use code identical to google's:

```
XsrfTokenServiceAsync xsrf = (XsrfTokenServiceAsync)GWT.create(XsrfTokenService.class);
((ServiceDefTarget)xsrf).setServiceEntryPoint(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "xsrf");
xsrf.getNewXsrfToken(new AsyncCallback<XsrfToken>() {

    public void onSuccess(XsrfToken token) {
        LoginServiceAsync rpc = (LoginServiceAsync)GWT.create(LoginService.class);
        ((HasRpcToken) rpc).setRpcToken(token);

        // make XSRF protected RPC call
        rpc.check(user, pass, new AsyncCallback<String>() {
            // ...
        });
    }

    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
        try {
             throw caught;
        } catch (RpcTokenException e) {
        // Can be thrown for several reasons:
        //   - duplicate session cookie, which may be a sign of a cookie
        //     overwrite attack
        //   - XSRF token cannot be generated because session cookie isn't
        //     present
        } catch (Throwable e) {
        // unexpected
    }
});
```

The complain is I that the call to getNewXsrfToken fails as it doesn't know that xsrf location from the call here: `GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "xsrf"`. I get the feeling there is a token handshake missing which causes this error, but I am not sure.

Lastly, I also tried implementing [Nick Siderakis' code](http://code.google.com/p/xsrf-safe/) but his example uses a JSP page which asks the server: `XsrfTokenUtil.getToken(request.getSession().getId())`. I do not want to use JSP pages and I have not figured out how to perform this without a jsp page. His code also diverges from the Google code example (i.e. he doesn't call getNewXsrfToken) which I do not know if it's the "prefered" google way of dealing with XSRF.

Any ideas as to what I am missing? Thanks.

**EDIT**

Solution below...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I figured out the problem. I had to change GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "xsrf" to "gwt/xsrf" in my code above as it wasn't pointing to the the right place, as I suspected. In addition, the server could not find a JSESSIONID cookie, so I followed [this](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6314) and added Cookies.setCookie("JSESSIONID", "JSESSIONID", null, null, "/", false); inside my onModuleLoad(). That did it. Cheers.

Comment: By the way, if you are using Tomcat you might want to use a different cookie name, like `session-id`, as suggested [here](http://blog.octo.com/gwt-et-securite-se-premunir-des-csrf/) to avoid cookie conflicts.

Comment: HI, btw which string did you use for session value on the XSRF cookie?.. do you always user random or?

Comment: Hi, not sure what you mean. getNewXsrfToken does not take in an argument and it returns an XsrfToken. Then you setRpcToken(token) which by extending XsrfProtectedServiceServlet in your RPC service implementation, you are given for free. As far as the session cookie, all you do is: HttpSession session = this.getThreadLocalRequest().getSession(); and then session.getId() gives you the session id.

Comment: well i saw my mestake... I was actually not generating a session from the javaserver, so the client had no cookie, so i needed to generate one on my own with the same name.. beacause i have a little more complicated architecture,and i need to use php-java bridge so i can share the same session, and as part of the php site, in javascript i am using XSRF on service toa javaserver, and I only had php session cookie, an no java session cookie... Thanks very much for your help, you helped me a lot in understanding how does this thing actually work :D

Comment: You're the man! Thanks. I think the instructions are rather unclear. I still have not idea what the little script thing in the `.jsp` script is supposed to do: `var into = { "xsrf" : "<%=XsrfTokenUtil.getToken(request.getSession().getId())%>" };` - no idea ..