# Recommended architecture for login in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, authentication

What would be the recommandations for designing a login screen in GWT?

I know that GWT is completely Async but the login process is fairly *binary*, you're either logged in now or never, but not something like perhaps later...

- Is there a way to make the client side wait?
- Should I have some kind of client side call back?

Any idea is appreciated...

Comment: Could you not replace the page with a "please wait" spinner once the process starts?

Comment: I could, but how do I make the client wait?

Comment: What do you mean? They have a please wait message, if they choose not no then there's nothing you can do. How does Google make people wait for their search results to return?

Comment: You already mentioned it. Use a callback. GWT communication between client and server is always programming with callbacks. You show a please wait message box, do a server request with the login credentials and install a callback for the login request. Then do nothing. The callback handler then checks, if the login was successfull and then shows the main panel.

Comment: TBH, the best architecture is to not do it within your app. _Protect_ your HTML host page, so when it's loaded you know the user is already logged in. Does not work in all cases though (but most cases).

Comment: We use RequestFactory and have put a "sniffer" in to detect auth failure (not logged in yet or timeout)... then we put up the login prompt (SSO/CAS) and retry the request when we think all is working. Shared, but not tidy, code here: https://github.com/salk31/gwt-rf-queue

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question re. client side wait.

Well, if it is a general login architecture question as in title then below are some references I found helpful:

[SO GWT cookies & redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2976062/1143684)

[SO GWT XSRF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298463/gwt-2-4-0-xsrf)

[GWT XSRF](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideSecurityRpcXsrf.html)

[GWT Login Page tutorial within Eclipse GWT Designer](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/tutorials/loginmanager?csw=1)